# Weblogic 11g: How to prevent download of JAR files from \webapp directory?

Tags: web-applications, webserver, weblogic, weblogic11g, weblogic12c

I have a couple of Java Applet JAR files in /webapp deployment of Weblogic domain. When I hit the URL:

```
http://localhost:7001/webapp/Applet.jar
```

The browser directly downloads the file JAR file specified in the URL. I want to prevent this behavior from a security point of view. Is there any way I can prevent this?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Specify security constraints in your web.xml file for URLs matching "/*.jar"

See the [Java EE Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/security-webtier002.htm#GKBAA)

Answer (score 0):

The applet is loaded from that path

if you disable it, the browser can also no longer download jar and cannot download the applet